# Why does SUM(some null value+0) return null in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

Why does SUM(some null value+0) return null in sql?

Ex.
SELECT SUM(CUST+0) FROM SOME_TABLE;

Assuming CUST column has all rows with null values.

The above query would evaluate SUM(CUST+0) to null for all columns.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Is it safe to use that anyway?

Comment: Because `Null` + anything is `Null`.  You should wrap it in `SUM(COALESCE(CUST, 0) + 0)` (Though, not sure why you're adding 0)

Comment: Not true, if you just do SELECT SUM(CUST) FROM SOME_TABLE; it will throw an error.

Comment: What is the datatype of Cust?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's related... Unless the datatype of Cust is something other than numeric

Comment: CUST is a long type.

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: cannot be used with non-numeric expressions

Comment: So `cust` *isn't* a `long` type.

Comment: If `cust` is a number then `SELECT SUM(CUST) FROM SOME_TABLE` will most definitely *not* throw an error.

Comment: Isn't `LONG` a blob-like datatype and therefor not numeric?

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT SUM(CUST+0)
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

This will return `NULL` *only* when all values of `CUST` are `NULL`.  `SUM()` -- like other aggregation functions -- generally ignores `NULL` values.  It only returns `NULL` when it doesn't have a choice, because all the values are `NULL`.

The code `+ 0` has no effect.  If `CUST` is `NULL` then `CUST + 0` is also `NULL`.  If `CUST` is not `NULL`, then `CUST + 0` is the same as `CUST` when `CUST` is numeric.

I would suggest you do the following:

```
SELECT SUM(CUST)
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

If `CUST` is not numeric, then don't use `SUM()`.  To get one value, use `MIN()` or `MAX()` instead.